# Spring Boot using ClientDetailsUserDetailsService to load ClientDetails

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am currently implementing an authentication flow with Spring Boot 2, this will allow BOTH Oauth, and Basic Authentication flows.

I want to use the OAuth table to facilitate authentication matching the client ID against the client secret. (I've read that this is the default behaviour within Spring,  and the `ClientDetailsUserDetailsService` certainly appears to implement things in this way.

The below reflects one of two configurations I currently have inside my app (the missing one being OAuth specific).

I currently get :

Description:

```
Field clientDetailsService in com.mydomain.core.Application$BasicAuthConfigurationAdapter required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
```

Wondering how to inject this class in, (building it as a Bean I assume is the way forward?)  and indeed if this is the correct approach to take in order to auth against the database (clientid and secret)

```
   @Order( 1 )
   @Configuration
   @Profile( "!test" )
   public static class BasicAuthConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
   {

      @Autowired
      private  ClientDetailsUserDetailsService clientDetailsService;

      @Bean
      public AuthenticationManager customAuthenticationManager() throws Exception
      {
         return authenticationManager();
      }


      @Override
      public void configure( HttpSecurity http ) throws Exception
      {
         http

                  .authorizeRequests()
                  .antMatchers( "/dummy/**" ).hasAnyRole( "ADMIN", "USER" )
                  .anyRequest()
                  .authenticated()
                  .and().httpBasic();
      }


      @Autowired
      public void configAuthentication( AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth ) throws Exception
      {
         auth.parentAuthenticationManager( authenticationManagerBean() ).userDetailsService( clientDetailsService );
      }

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

We have configured the ClientDetailsService like the following:

```js
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
class OAuth2Configuration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

// TODO: Configure clients through a clientDetails service
    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        ClientDetailsService jdbcClientDetailsServiceBuilder = clients.jdbc(dataSource).build();
        try {
            jdbcClientDetailsServiceBuilder.loadClientByClientId(sClientName);
        } catch (NoSuchClientException noSuchClientException) {
            logger.error("message={Caught Exception {}}", noSuchClientException.getMessage(), noSuchClientException);
            // @formatter:off
            clients.jdbc(dataSource).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder).withClient(sServiceClientName)
                    .authorizedGrantTypes(syntheticsServiceClientGrantTypes).authorities(sConstants.ROLE_USER)
                    .scopes(s.OAUTH2_WRITE_SCOPE).resourceIds(OAUTH2_DEFAULT_RESOURCE_ID)
                    .secret(sServiceClientSecret);
            // @formatter:on
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("message={Caught Exception {}}", e.getMessage(), e);

        }
    }


}
```

the WebSecurityConfiguration only has the auth provider.

This is a good resource to help figure out the different components: https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/